# Drawing a cartesian diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

I want to draw a rectangle into the right square of the following diagram:

[image]

The code to produce that image is the following:

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
fontsize=12pt,
titlepage,
%draft,
%twoside,
final
]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let
\begin{equation*} 
    \begin{tikzcd} 
        X'' \ar[r,] \ar[d,] &  X' \ar[d]\ar[r]  & X\ar[d]  \\
        S'' \ar[r]& S' \ar[r] & S
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
    be a diagram in $\mathcal{C}$. 
    
\end{document}
```

How would one do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have drawn a rectangle into the right square of your diagram.
[image]

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
fontsize=12pt,
titlepage,
%draft,
%twoside,
final
]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let
\begin{equation*} 
    \begin{tikzcd} 
        X'' \ar[r] \ar[d] &  X' \ar[d] \ar[dr, phantom, "\square"] \ar[r] & X\ar[d]  \\
        S'' \ar[r]& S' \ar[r] & S
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
    be a diagram in $\mathcal{C}$. 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you:)